# Script optimization for massive updates

Tags: python, mysql, optimization, sql-update

I'm working on a script which creates a hash of some data and save it in the database. The data needed come from a SQL query which join around 300k rows with 500k rows. While parsing results, I create the hash value and update in the db using a second connexion handler (using the first one gives me a "Unread results" error).

After a lot of investigations, I figured out that what give me the best results in terms of performances are the following:

- Restart the select query every x iterations. Otherwise, updates become a lot slower after a certain time
- Commit only every 200 queries instead of committing on every query
- Tables used for the select query are MyISAM and indexed with primary key and fields used in join.
- My hash table is InnoDB and there's only the primary key (id) which is indexed.

Here's my script:

```
commit = ''       
stillgoing = True    
limit1 = 0
limit2 = 50000    
i = 0    
while stillgoing:    
    j = 0    
    # rerun select query every 50000 results
    getProductsQuery = ("SELECT distinct(p.id), p.desc, p.macode, p.manuf, "
        "u.unit, p.weight, p.number, att1.attr as attribute1, p.vcode, att2.attr as attribute2 "
        "FROM p "
        "LEFT JOIN att1 on p.id = att1.attid and att1.attrkey = 'PARAM' "
        "LEFT JOIN att2 on p.id = att2.attid and att2.attrkey = 'NODE' "
        "LEFT JOIN u on p.id = u.umid and u.lang = 'EN' "
        "limit "+str(limit1)+", "+str(limit2))                           
    db.query(getProductsQuery)
    row = db.fetchone()              
    while row is not None:
        i += 1
        j += 1
        id = str(row[0])
        # create hash value
        to_hash = '.'.join( [ helper.tostr(s) for s in row[1:]] )
        hash = hashlib.md5(to_hash.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        # set query
        updQuery = ("update hashtable set hash='"+hash+"' where id="+id+" limit 1" )         
        # commit every 200 queries
        commit = 'no'
        if (i%200==0):
            i = 0
            commit = 'yes'
        # db2 is a second instance of db connexion
        # home made db connexion class
        # query function takes two parameters: query, boolean for commit
        db2.query(updQuery,commit)            
        row = db.fetchone()        
    if commit == 'no':
        db2.cnx.commit()            
    if j < limit2:
        stillgoing = False
    else:
        limit1 += limit2
```

Currently the script takes between 1 hour 30 and 2 hours to run completely. These are the better performances I got since the very first version of the script. Is there anything I can do to make it run faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
... LIMIT 0,200  -- touches 200 rows
... LIMIT 200,200  -- touches 400 rows
... LIMIT 400,200  -- touches 600 rows
... LIMIT 600,200  -- touches 800 rows
...
```

Get the picture?  LIMIT + OFFSET is O(N*N).  Quadraticly slow.

To get it down to O(N), you need to do a single *linear* scan.  If the single query (with no LIMIT/OFFSET), takes too long, then walk though the table in 'chunks':

```
... WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 200  -- 200 rows
... WHERE id BETWEEN 201 AND 400  -- 200 rows
... WHERE id BETWEEN 401 AND 600  -- 200 rows
... WHERE id BETWEEN 601 AND 800  -- 200 rows
```

I blog about such [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).  If the table you are updating is InnoDB and has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, then chunking by `id` is very efficient.

You could have `autocommit=1` so that each 200-row `UPDATE` automatically `COMMITs`.

Oh, your table are using the antique Engine, MyISAM?  Well, it will run reasonably well.

Comment: Now the script takes around 1 hour. There is probably something else to review but this is already a good improvement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this entirely within MySQL:

```
updateProductsQuery = "
    UPDATE hashtable AS h
    JOIN p ON h.id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN att1 on p.id = att1.attid and att1.attrkey = 'PARAM'
    LEFT JOIN att2 on p.id = att2.attid and att2.attrkey = 'NODE' 
    LEFT JOIN u on p.id = u.umid and u.lang = 'EN'
    SET h.hash = MD5(CONCAT_WS('.', p.desc, p.macode, p.manuf, u.unit, p.weight, p.number, att1.attr, p.vcode, att2.attr))
    LIMIT " + str(limit1) + ", " + str(limit2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems there's no way I can run this query. Limit doesn't work and every time I got timeout error (even with a higher timeout set up)